# Spark in standalone mode on a single computer : is it worth splitting it in masters and workers through docker containers (or another way)?

Tags: docker, apache-spark, kubernetes, minikube

I currently own only one computer, and I won't have another.

1. I run *Spark* on its CPU cores : `master=local[5]`, using it directly : I set `spark-core` and `spark-sql` for dependencies, do quite no other configuration, and my programs start immediately. It's confortable, of course.
2. But should I attempt to create an architecture with a master and some workers by the mean of *Docker* containers or *minikube* (*Kubernetes*) on my computer ?

Will solution **#2** - with all the settings it requires - reward me with better performances, because *Spark* is truly designed to work that way, even on a single computer,

or will I loose some time, because the mode I'm currently running it, without network usage, without need of data locality will always give me better performances, and solution **#1** will always be the best on a single computer ?

My hypothesis is that **#1** is fine. But I have no true measurement for that. No source of comparison. Who have experienced the two manners of doing things on a sigle computer ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It really depends on your goals - if you always will run your Spark code on the single node with local master, then just use it.  But if you intend to run your resulting code in the distributed mode on multiple machines, then emulating cluster with Docker could be useful, as you'll get your code running in truly distributed manner, and you'll able to find problems that not always are found when you run your code with the local master.

Instead of direct Docker usage (that could be tricky to setup, although it's still possible), maybe you can consider to use Spark on Kubernetes, for example, via minikube - there is a plenty of articles found by Google on this topic.

Comment: Your idea is my hypothesis : stay with local settings and not attempting to create a set of containers would be the best thing to do. But I'm looking for experiences that people have concretely led to know what their observations are.

Comment: I'm talking from the my personal hands-on experience from several years ago using Docker + Spark, and it required quite a lot of effort :-)

Answer (score 2):

Having done testing on this with executor size, the cutover from when it makes sense to use more multiple executors is # CPUs > 32.  AWS EMR spark runtime defaults to at least 4 CPUs per executor and Databricks always uses fat executors which means > 32CPUS on the 8xl instances.  Your greatest limitation tends to be the JVMs garbage collection which caps the size of the heap. Local mode has a couple performance advantages compared to cluster mode.

1. full stage code gen has to be run on both the drive and every single executor.  For short queries this can add several 100MS per stage.
2. driver <-> executor communication has latency.
3. shared memory between driver and executors.  This reduces the chance of OOM and reduces the amount of spilling to disk.

People end up choosing to go with multiple executors/instances not because it would be faster than a single instance but because it is the only way to scale up in terms of data volume and parallization. (also for failure recovery)

If you're feeling ambitious there's a performance testing tool called TPC-DS that runs a set of dataprocessing queries against a standardized dataset

https://github.com/databricks/spark-sql-perf
https://github.com/maropu/spark-tpcds-datagen

Also if you're feeling adventurous the spark code has a script to fire up a mini cluster on minikube if you want a quick and easy way to test this.